# How to hook google analytics into parsleyjs events

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, parsley.js, dom-events

In my application I want to send a google analytics event when a parsleyjs validation error occurs.

This is the approach I've come up with so far but I'm finding it wanting.

```
  $("#myForm").parsley().on("field:error", function(e) {
    var label = $("label[for='" + e.$element.attr("id") + "']").text() || "No label",
      errorMessage = e.getErrorsMessages().join(" ") || "No message";

    ga("send", "event", "error - field", label, errorMessage);
  });
```

This would be something that I would want to do to every form that has the parsley method run on it.  Rather than do this same code for every single form, is there a way I can configure or extend parsley to do this?

Or if there is a better approach then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsley's events can be listened to globally.

`Parsley.on("field:error", ...)`